# how to pass parameter to stored procedure using mysql

Tags: mysql

Im trying to add parameter to this stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `mifostenant-default`.`test` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `mifostenant-default`.`test` ()

BEGIN

select * from employees 

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to make a procedure and pass a parameter to it:

```
delimiter $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `mifostenant-default`.`test`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `mifostenant-default`.`test` (IN empName CHAR(20))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employee_name=empName;
END $$
delimiter ;
```

And you call your procedure as below:

```
CALL  mifostenant-default.test(the_parameter_to_pass);
```